Sharing web map to Enterprise from ArcGIS Pro
I am just getting used to sharing to Enterprise having mostly just used ArcGIS Pro until now.  I am making a web map and having troubles sharing it and though I have looked through Esri support pages and some YouTube videos, nothing seems straight forward on the issues I have so trying here.
The contents of my web map has vector tile layers that live on our internal network, as well as Feature Class layers that come from File Geodatabases also on our internal network.  Everything in ArcGIS Pro displays fine and works.
Now I want this ArcGIS Pro project to become a web map, so in the Share group of the toolbar I have chosen "Web Map".  The properties pane opens and I put in name, summary, tags, etc.  For configuration I have chosen "Copy all data: Editable" as I want people to be able to edit the Feature Layers that the Feature Classes will be converted into once in Enterprise.  I set the portal folder and share settings, but when I analyze I get errors that the Vector Tile layers are not supported.  My guess is because they're Vector Tiles and therefore not editable but the configuration setting says to be able to edit.
So I tried a different approach and thought maybe I need to have the Vector Tile shared to Enterprise already and then consume it in my web map in ArcGIS Pro from Enterprise and not from the Vector Tile package that exists on our local network.  So I opened a new ArcGIS Pro project, added in the VT package and tried to share that as a Web Layer instead of Web Map, and in the configuration told it to use Vector Tiles and make a copy instead of reference the data, but I still get a message that the data source is unsupported.
What am I missing here?
If I'm thinking about this workflow of web mapping all wrong, perhaps you can point me to an Esri video that walks through it. I have watched a few though and everything in the videos seems to work fine, but I also have not found a video that shows a web map in ArcGIS Pro with a combination of VT and FC's coming together to make a web map, which is my situation.
