Choosing map to add feature layer into using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro
I am building a model to create vector tiles to upload into Enterprise, and these VT's must be in WGS Web Mercator, while our source data is in a different coordinate system.  I want to leave the source in the existing coordinate system, while still being able to make a vector tile index of the projected version.
However, the Create Vector Tile Index geoprocess requires the setting of the map to
I have the model projecting the data into the proper coordinate system, but I want to add the result into a separate map tab in the same project, so that in subsequent model steps it ignores the original dataset map and processes the map tab that has the projected dataset in it.
I suppose I could make the map selection a parameter variable but it would be nice if we had a standard map name in all projects this model will be run in that we could have it point to.
Any suggestions on making that model bring the projected data into a different map tab than the one the source is in, or am I thinking about this all wrong?

May be related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/487546/115

If you're ok to use Python, this is doable with arcpy.
